# converting org.openrdf.model.impl.GraphImpl to info.aduna.iteration.Iteration

Tags: rdf, sesame

I have a graph object of class org.openrdf.model.impl.GraphImpl and I can get out of it org.openrdf.model.util.PatternIterator or could call .iterator() on it.
I'm trying to utilize this add method from org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryConnection:

```
add(info.aduna.iteration.Iteration, org.openrdf.model.Resource)
```

So far I had no success getting the graph's iterator or PatternIterator converted to info.aduna.iteration.Iteration, although it seems like it should be a straight forward thing. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since Sesame release 2.7.0, `org.openrdf.model.Graph` (and the default `GraphImpl` implementation) are deprecated, in favor of the `org.openrdf.model.Model` interface (with the accompanying `LinkedHashModel` and `TreeModel` implementations). If you are using Sesame 2.7.0 or higher, you might want to consider switching to using `Model`, as it is more feature-rich and generally easier to use (see the [relevant section in the userdocs](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.8/docs/programming.docbook?view#The_RDF_Model_API) for details).

However, since both `Model` and `Graph` extend `java.util.Collection`, and therefore are both `java.lang.Iterable` instances, you can easily add them to a store by just using `RepositoryConnection.add(Iterable<? extends Statement> statements, Resource... contexts)` instead.

In other words, instead of trying to convert to an `Iteration` somehow, you can simply do this:

```java
Model model = new LinkedHashModel();
Graph graph = new GraphImpl();

...
RepositoryConnection conn = repo.getConnection();
conn.add(model); // a Model is an Iterable, so this works
conn.add(graph); // a Graph is an Iterable, so this works
```